# Salesforce FuelSDK

Tags: php, salesforce

I am trying to set up Salesforce FuelSDK so i cann add subscribers to a list.
I am stuck at this part right now , where i cant seem to make the baseUrl work.
These are my php configs

```
return array(
    'appsignature' => 'none', 
    'clientid' => 'test',
    'clientsecret' => 'test',
    'defaultwsdl' => 'https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl',
    'xmlloc' => 'wdsl/ExactTargetWSDL.xml',
    'baseAuthUrl' => 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com',
    'baseUrl' => 'https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx'
);
```

And this is giving me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unable to determine stack using /platform/v1/endpoints/: Unable to determine stack using /platform/v1/endpoints/:<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body> <h2>Object moved to <a href="/Error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/Service.asmx/platform/v1/endpoints/soap">here</a>.</h2> </body></html> in /home/vagrant/Code/marketing_cloud/src/ET_Client.php on line 180
```

If anyone could help it would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem here is the baseURL
'baseUrl' => 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/'